How to fix codeblock blocking execution
async function getMatchesByFixtureId(id){

  let count = 0;
  let request = true;
  let response;

  const options = {
    method: 'GET',
    url: 'https://api-football-v1.p.rapidapi.com/v3/fixtures',
    params: {id: id},
    headers: {
      'x-rapidapi-key': API_KEY,
      'x-rapidapi-host': 'api-football-v1.p.rapidapi.com'
    }
  };

  async function innerFunction(){
    
    
      if(request === true){

        response = await axios.request(options);
        const match = response.data.response;
        console.log(match);
        let status;
        console.log(1);


              if(["CANC", "FT", "AET", "PEN", "PST", "AWD", "WO"].includes(match.fixture.status.short)){
                status = "FT";
                if(count === 4){
                  request = false;
                }
                count++;
              }
              
              else if(["TBD", "NS"].includes(match.fixture.status.short)){
                status = "SC";
                count = 0;
              }
              else if(["HT", "LIVE", "1H", "2H", "ET", "BT", "P"].includes(match.fixture.status.short)){
                status="LIVE";
                count = 0;
              }
  
          console.log(2);
          
  
        const fixture = {
           Bunch of data
        }
  
        console.log(3);
  
        
        await client.db("db").collection("matches").replaceOne(fixture);

      }

      else{
        return;
      }

  }

  const task = cron.schedule("* * * * *", async() => {
    
    await innerFunction();

  }, {timezone: "UTC"});
  task.start();

  setTimeout(task.stop, 8.1e+6)

}

So basically the getMatchesByFixtureId() above is called by another function which schedules the execution of getMatchesByFixtureId() and getMatchesByFixtureId() requests from api-football a live football match with the matching fixture id every minute.
The problem is that  the code between console.log(1) and console.log(2) blocks the execution of the code bellow and when I comment it out the code between console.log(2) and console.log(3) blocks the code below if anyone is wondering yes the api request work fine I receive the right data

try to simplify your example, reducing it to the smallest possible code the reproduces the problem. be more specific when you say "the code below". if there are two problems, reduce it to just one. doing this will make it easier for us to understand what's going on.

The problem was that the data I received was in an array so I had to select position 0 of the array.
const match = response.data.response; -> const match = response.data.response[0];
